# Getting data in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having problem to retrive data in php arrays.

```
var_dump($temp->Odds[0]);
```

output

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#22 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["Id"]=> string(9) "100750488" ["Name"]=> string(1) "-" } [0]=> string(4) "1.39" }
```

I want to get this "1.39"

Comment: Did you try `(string)$temp->Odds[0]` ?

Comment: ... I knew it's so easy that it's even shame to ask - THX a lot